# Anaconda 3 for Linux Has No ensurepip?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-venv

This is my environment:

- CentOS 64-bit 7.2.1511
- Anaconda 3 4.1.1 64-bit (Python 3.5.2)

I want to create venv virtual environment by `pyvenv`. Unfortunately, I got this error message:

`$ pyvenv test
Error: Command '['/root/test/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1`

After searching the Internet, people said the module `ensurepip` is missing. I checked my Anaconda installation path `/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.5`. There is no ensurepip folder.

Then, on my Windows 10 64-bit, I checked my Anaconda installation path `D:\win10\Anaconda3\Lib\`. There is an ensurepip folder! And I can successfully run `python -m venv test` to create a venv.

Then, I checked the download Anaconda python archives:
`D:\win10\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.5.2-0.tar.bz2` on Windows 10
and
`/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.2-0.tar.bz2` on CentOS 7.

The one archive on Windows 10 does has a ensurepip subfolder. But the one on CentOS 7 doesn't!

Does anyone know this difference? Is it a bug of Anaconda?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, Anaconda3/2 for Linux and Mac OS do not have `ensurepip` installed.

According to [this issue record](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/952), it is NOT a bug, this is done *intentionally* when the Python in Anaconda being compiled without the `--with-ensurepip=install` flag.

I think the rationale (of Continuum Analytics) is that, *in Anaconda Distribution*, `conda` is the boss to manage the packages and virtual environments, and

> pip (and it's setuptools dependency) are installed independent of Python **as conda packages**.

So instead of running `pyvenv test`, you can first run `pyvenv test --without-pip`, then download the `get-pip.py` from [pip's homepage](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py), and install the pip in **activated** `test` venv.

Just like the following:

```
$ #===== First create the venv without pip, and **activate** it.
$ pyvenv test --without-pip
$ cd test/
$ ls bin/
activate       activate.csh   activate.fish  python@        python3@
$ echo $PATH
Whatever/Else:In/Your/System
$ source bin/activate
(test) $ echo $PATH
/Users/YaOzI/test/bin:Whatever/Else:In/Your/System
(test) $
(test) $ #===== Then install the pip independently.
(test) $ python ~/Downloads/get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-26.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (459kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 460kB 1.3MB/s 
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 5.7MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed pip-8.1.2 setuptools-26.0.0 wheel-0.29.0
(test) $ ls bin/
activate   activate.fish     easy_install-3.5*  pip3*  python@   wheel*
activate.csh  easy_install*  pip*     pip3.5*   python3@
(test) $
(test) $ #===== Now you can play around with pip
(test) $ pip list
(test) $
```