# cannot load Python 3.5 interpreter for virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have installed Python 3.5 through Anaconda on the OSX system. After installing and activating the virtual environment,

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

The Python version is Python 2.7.10. And while we are allowed to load the interpreter of our choice in [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), "/usr/bin/" only has folders for Python 2.6 and 2.7. After finding out the Anaconda python 3.5 path (   /Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python3.5)
and trying to load it,

> for: virtualenv -p /Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python3.5 venv

the code returns a [Errno 13] Permission Denied

```
> Running virtualenv with interpreter /Users/Username/anaconda/lib/python3.5
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv",
> line 11, in <module>
>     sys.exit(main())   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 790, in main
>     popen = subprocess.Popen([interpreter, file] + sys.argv[1:], env=env)   File
> "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 710, in __init__
>     errread, errwrite)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 1335, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

> for: virtualenv -p /Users/Username/anaconda/bin/python3.5 venv

there seems to be another type of error...

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Users/Username/anaconda/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/Users/Username/anaconda'
New python executable in venv/bin/python3.5
Not overwriting existing python script venv/bin/python (you must use venv/bin/python3.5)
ERROR: The executable venv/bin/python3.5 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/Username/.../targetfolder' (should be '/Users/Username/.../targetfolder/venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Comment: You could use the `-p` option to specify the path to Anaconda's Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: anaconda's python is usually automatically found, at least on ubuntu. when outside the virtualenv, does `python` use the anaconda python?

Comment: yes, when outside of virtualenv it uses the Python 3.5. but still figuring out how to load it into virtualenv...

Comment: Try bin/python3.5 instead of lib/python3.5 ?

Comment: Thanks! now the permission error disappears but another error seems to emerge, please see my updated question for more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ERROR: The executable venv/bin/python3.5 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/Username/.../targetfolder' (should be '/Users/Username/.../targetfolder/venv')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

This error results from trying to combine incompatible versions of Python and the virtualenv tool.  I'm not sure precisely where the incompatibility comes from, but I do know how to work around it.

Assuming your Python is reasonably functional and recent (read: 3.3 or later), this should always work:

```
/path/to/python3.5 -m venv venv
```

The first venv is the [venv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).  The second is the name of the directory where you want to create a virtualenv.  This command asks Python to create a virtualenv itself, rather than shelling out to a third-party tool.  Thus, we can be reasonably confident Python will do it correctly, and in particular that it will not be incompatible with itself.

---

Unfortunately, the version of Python installed with Anaconda cannot be described as "reasonably functional" because [it lacks `ensurepip`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524856/anaconda-3-for-linux-has-no-ensurepip).  That makes it impossible for the venv module to bootstrap `pip` into your virtualenv.  So you will need to build your venv without pip, and then install it manually:

```
/path/to/python3.5 -m venv --without-pip venv
```

Then download and run [`get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) from within the virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks! As stated I am on Python 3.5 so should have worked... below are the outputs though: 
Unable to symlink '/Users/Username/anaconda/bin/python3.5' to '/Users/targetfolder/venv/bin/python3.5', Error: Command '['targetpath/venv/bin/python3.5', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status -11

Comment: Try it with the `--copies` flag?  If that fails, you might have to use `--without-pip`, which is rather inconvenient.

Comment: thanks! can you elaborate a bit more? is `/path/to/python3.5 -m venv venv
--copies` what you mean?

Comment: That will *probably* work but pedantically it should be after the module name and before the target directory name (so `-m venv --copies venv`).  Also, if the target directory already exists (because you did not clean it up after a previous run), you must pass the `--clear` flag to tell the venv module to remove the existing cruft.

Comment: thanks so much for the instructions! didn't expect that Anaconda python can be this tricky and some steps need to be taken. all issues can be resolved using the method provided.